# Cordova UWP installs on Desktop, but not Mobile

Tags: windows, cordova, uwp, ionic3

I have an Ionic 3 Cordova application where I have built it for the Windows UWP platform. I have tested this in office by side loading onto both my desktop, and onto a Surface tablet.

I've submitted to the store, and check both Windows 10 and Windows Mobile as shown below...

[image]

I selected the Mobile thinking this would cover the tablet option. I don't have an actual Windows **Phone** to test on, but just assumed this would be the same as the tablet.

After submitting to the store, I havethe following reported back..

> Installs on:
> Desktop
>
> Does not install on:
> Mobile
>
> Tested Devices: Windows 10 Desktop, Windows 10 Mobile

In my `config.xml`, I have only the following set

```
 <preference name="windows-target-version" value="10.0" />
```

I have built for just x86, but I thought the Universal meant it would install on any Windows 10 device? Any ideas on what I may need to do?

Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows 10 Mobile runs only on ARM processors so you'll have to add the ARM architecture to the outputting package.

Speaking about architectures.. Why don't you add x64?

Comment: Thanks for that, I added both the x64 and arm, and now all is good.